# Common dependency in Kubernetes Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Imagine we have following construction:

- Chart A contains App A and a MongoDB Server V3
- Chart B contains App B and a MongoDB Server V4
- Chart C contains App C and a MongoDB Server V4

We have the problem that `Helm` in this case creates three MongoDB instances: 1x V3 and 2x V4. We have expected `Helm` detects the existing V4 and does not create another one.

Now we are looking for a way for `Helm` to install services only if they do not yet exist. In our case, this applies not only to databases, but also to applications.

We can't put everything in a single chart. We have a basic chart for our core applications, and then own charts per customer.

Comment: We use helmfile for these types of dependencies in helm. While still maintaining the ability to have the chart authors update their charts independently.  https://github.com/roboll/helmfile.  In its website,  Helmfile is a declarative spec for deploying helm charts. It lets you...

Keep a directory of chart value files and maintain changes in version control.
Apply CI/CD to configuration changes.
Periodically sync to avoid skew in environments.

Comment: @BalChua thanks I will take a look!